# the usage of "behold" here confuses me

Tags: parsing

> On the rooftop **behold** a 300-meter landscape garden divided into zones including a 'pause area' for quiet contemplation.

Since **behold** means **see**, I would write: On the rooftop **we can behold** a 300-meter landscape garden divided into zones including a 'pause area' for quiet contemplation.

If the original sentence is not wrong, please tell me what is the subject and verb.

Comment: The original is OK but your re-write sounds very unnatural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the imperative (command) form. In the imperative, the implied subject is “you.” It is simply instructing you to notice the garden.

It would have been better to add a comma after “rooftop,” but the sentence is grammatically correct.